# CRONTAB Executar por um determinado tempo

Tags: cron

Olá estou com problemas em executar o document root do php diretamente no crontab

regra atual funcionando corretamente

> 23 23 * * * sleep 33 && wget -t 1 -T 1800
>   http://www.dominio.com.br/script.php

Explicações
23:23 //execute todos os dias as onze e vinte e três
sleep 33 //aguarde 33 segundo dos 23 minutos para iniciar
wget //chama a url
-t 1 //execute somente uma vez
-T 1800 //execute por 1800 segundos, caso contrario mate o processo

eu gostaria de trocar a chamada executação diretamente do php ex:

> 23 23 * * * sleep 33 && php -f /document_root/script.php

//o exemplo acima funciona!
//gostaria de saber o que é -f?
//tentei adicionar o -t 1 nas seguintes formas abaixo, porem, nenhuma funcionou

> 23 23 * * * sleep 33 && php -f -t 1 /document_root/script.php //nao
>   funciona 23 23 * * * sleep 33 && php -t 1 /document_root/script.php
>   //nao funciona 23 23 * * * sleep 33 && php -t 1 -f
>   /document_root/script.php //nao funciona 23 23 * * * sleep 33 && php
>   -f /document_root/script.php -t 1 //nao funciona 23 23 * * * sleep 33 && -t 1 php -f /document_root/script.php //nao funciona

alguém ja passou por isso?
Obrigado
Marco

Comment: O comando PHP não possui controle de *timeout*; você precisará controlar isso direto no código.

Comment: anderson no meu exemplo acima o proprio cron tem isso na chamada wget, porem não sei utilizar isso na chamada php no cron, não no script php da execução